# How to setup two Spring projects with different datasources (xml vs annotations)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have a question regarding a proof of concept that I am trying to create.

I want to create a new Spring project based on Java 17 and Spring Boot 3 that contains a REST API implementation.

I also have existing Spring projects in older versions which are XML based. They contain already some service classes that I need to call from the new REST API services. They communicate with different databases (Oracle, IBM DB2).

Also, the new project should run on Hibernate 6.x while the existing projects will continue running on Hibernate 5.x. And finally, the new project will use JPA repositories, while the old ones use a classical DAO approach in Hibernate directly.

---

To test this concept I created two projects:

- spring-xml with Hibernate 5 and XML based configuration
- spring-ann with Hibernate 6 and annotation-based configuration (=REST API project)

So far I am able to run the REST project and it seems like it also correctly loads the beans of the XML project because I see that the service has an initialized DAO in it and also I am able to access the Hibernate session.

However, I am not able to persist the entity of the XML project. I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.springxml.springxml.PoCEntityXml
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.getEntityDescriptor(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1492) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState.getEntityState(EntityState.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:628) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:620) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:615) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at com.springxml.springxml.PoCDAO.insert(PoCDAO.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.springxml.springxml.PoCServiceXml.insert(PoCServiceXml.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.springann.springann.PoCService.insert(PoCService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.springann.springann.PoCController.poc(PoCController.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:537) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

If I run the xml project on its own, it is working properly. So for sure, there is something wrong when calling it from the REST project and I don't know why.

---

Here are some files of the PoC project. I will explain the different steps that I tried afterwards.

---

**XML project**

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="mariadb_ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/spring_xml_db"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mariadb_sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mariadb_ds"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springxml.springxml"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.springxml.springxml.PoCEntityXml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="mariadb_tm" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mariadb_sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="com.springxml.springxml.PoCDAO">
        <constructor-arg ref="mariadb_sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="service" class="com.springxml.springxml.PoCServiceXml">
        <property name="dao" ref="dao"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/spring_xml_db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

PoCDAO:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PoCDAO {
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void insert() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(
                PoCEntityXml.builder()
                        .id(new Random().nextLong())
                        .lastName("Mustermann")
                        .build()
        );
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

PoCEntityXml:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POC_ENTITY")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PoCEntityXml {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
}
```

PoCServiceXml:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PoCServiceXml {
    private PoCDAO dao;

    public void insert() {
        dao.insert();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-xml</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

**REST project (annotations)**

SpringApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.springxml.springxml", "com.springann.springann"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.springxml.springxml", "com.springann.springann"})
public class SpringAnnApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringAnnApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

PoCService

```
@Service
//@Import(PoCServiceXml.class)
@ImportResource("classpath:context.xml")
public class PoCService {

    private final PoCRepository repository;
    private final PoCServiceXml xmlService;

    public PoCService(PoCRepository repository, PoCServiceXml xmlService) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.xmlService = xmlService;
    }

    public void insert() {
        repository.save(
                PoCEntity.builder()
                        .id(new Random().nextLong(2L, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                        .lastName("Mustermann Ann")
                        .build()
        );

        xmlService.insert();
    }
}
```

PoCEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POC_ENTITY")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PoCEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Configuration for datasource of xml project:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.springxml.springxml"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mariadbEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mariadbTransactionManager"
)
public class MariadbCfg {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.mariadb")
    public DataSourceProperties mariadbDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.mariadb.configuration")
    public DataSource mariadbDataSource(@Qualifier("mariadbDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties mariadbDataSourceProperties) {
        return mariadbDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder mariadbEntityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), new HashMap<>(), null);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mariadbEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder mariadbEntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
            @Qualifier("mariadbDataSource") DataSource mariadbDataSource
    ) {

        Map<String, String> mariadbJpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        mariadbJpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");
        mariadbJpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");

        return mariadbEntityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(mariadbDataSource)
                .packages("com.springxml.springxml")
                // .persistenceUnit("mariadbDataSource")
                .properties(mariadbJpaProperties)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager mariadbTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("mariadbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory mariadbEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mariadbEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

configuration of data source for REST:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.springann.springann"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "postgresTransactionManager"
)
public class PostgresCfg {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.postgres")
    public DataSourceProperties postgresDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.postgres.configuration")
    public DataSource postgresDataSource(@Qualifier("postgresDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties postgresDataSourceProperties) {
        return postgresDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder postgresEntityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), new HashMap<>(), null);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgresEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder postgresEntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
            @Qualifier("postgresDataSource") DataSource postgresDataSource
    ) {

        Map<String, String> postgresJpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        postgresJpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        postgresJpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");

        return postgresEntityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(postgresDataSource)
                .packages("com.springann.springann")
                // .persistenceUnit("postgresDataSource")
                .properties(postgresJpaProperties)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager postgresTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("postgresEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory postgresEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(postgresEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springann</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ann</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-ann</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.springxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/klaus2/IdeaProjects/spring-xml/target/spring-xml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

I was hoping that adding the XML project as a dependency to the REST project is sufficient and then just use `@ImportResource` to load and configure the beans of the XML project. But that did not work out for me so I tried already several other steps:

- Add the XML package to the packages to scan in `@SpringBootApplication` and `@EntityScan`
- Setup the XML project data source separately in the REST project (see `MariadbCfg` and `PostgresCfg` above. MariaDB is used in the XML project)
- Adding `annotatedClasses` to the session factory configuration in the xml project. Also, adding the `packagesToScan` cfg.

Any idea on how to solve that would be great!

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:** Looking at the stacktrace I realized it is an error thrown by Hibernate 6 but in fact for the xml project it should use Hibernate 5. Maybe that is not even possible?